# getting too many follow-up request as response of request

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, retrofit, http-error

we have a Restful web service created using `Jersey` and running on `TomEE 7.0.3`

we are using Android platform for client-side and it's using `Retrofit` for having communication with the server.

our system is modular and contains more than 14 parts.

about 3 weeks (until now), sometimes the clients getting `too many follow-up requests` as the response.

we searched for it in here and [retrofit issues in github](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1561).

they said that it might be server falt so we trace the request with `ngrep` command on the server.

we saw that server was getting the request and also responding to it correctly even when clients get `follow-up`.

we also test this matter with different networks and this matter still remains.

so what else could cause this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after several tests, we realized that this error is only on Android platforms (we tested the APIs with Postman when Android platforms were receiving `Too many follow up request`.

so after some more tests, we found out, when Android platforms get `408` as a response code they show this message. we changed the status code and this problem fixed.

I put this issue on `square/okhttp` repository in github and they put the `bug` flag on it.

you can see it [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3827)

**---- update ----**

they said it fixed in `OkHttp v3.10`

Comment: It still happing at 3.11.0 version. :(

Comment: @HugoLandim Please send open an issue or reopen mine, in okhttp repository to fix this problem as soon as possible